# Android windowSoftInputMode not working

Tags: android, cordova, android-layout

I am developing a mobile app based on cordova. My problem is that when I launch the soft keyboard, the page itself don't scroll to the bottom, so the textbox stays behind the keyboard.
In the AndroidManifest i set the **android:windowSoftInputMode** to **adjustResize** and to **adjustPan**, but no results. The awkward thing is that if i have the application with horizontal orientation, the keyboard stays below the textbox, but in vertical orientation it does not.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: I am not programming with android sdk. My mobile app it's based on html, javascript and css in order to be cross-platform

Comment: Did you fixed it? I've got the same problem